# Android pass long value to class View

Tags: android, class, view, calendar, long-integer

I'm using the library [WeekView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/970) When the application starts, I want to pass to class View the date from calendar for set the first day of view.
In the Activity, I set the calendar, and pass it to class:

```
calendarioFooter.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
mWeekView = (WeekView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.weekView);
mWeekView.setOnEventClickListener(this);
mWeekView.setEmptyViewClickListener(this);
mWeekView.setMonthChangeListener(this);
mWeekView.setEventLongPressListener(this);
mWeekView.setDataRicevuta(calendarioFooter.getTimeInMillis());
```

In the class View, set the calendar:

```
public class WeekView extends View {
    private Long data_ricevuta;

    public void setDataRicevuta(Long data_ricevuta) {
        this.data_ricevuta = data_ricevuta;
    }

    public Long get_data_ricevuta() {
        return data_ricevuta;
    }

    private void init() {
        ...
        mToday = Calendar.getInstance();
        mToday.setTimeInMillis(data_ricevuta); 
        mToday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        mToday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        mToday.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

but the app crashed and I have this error:

```
04-24 18:43:35.546: E/AndroidRuntime(6049): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.alamkanak.weekview.WeekView
```

**however if I add one day manually, it works.
Thanks for the help**

```
mToday = Calendar.getInstance();
mToday.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
mToday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
mToday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
mToday.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Comment: where are the constructors in your View's subclass

Comment: Calendar.DATE is an int not a Long You are also doing two different operations here, can you please be more specific about what your trying to do.

Comment: I want to pass the calendar, not add a day. I added a day just to try.

Comment: See answer below the `Calendar#setTimeInMillis` wants a `long` not a `Long`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Calendar Docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis(long)

setTimeInMillis Takes a long not a Long

```
private long data_ricevuta;
public void setDataRicevuta(long data_ricevuta) {
    this.data_ricevuta = data_ricevuta;
}
public long get_data_ricevuta() {
    return data_ricevuta;
}
```

change your call

`mWeekView.setDataRicevuta(calendarioFooter.getTimeInMillis());`

to

`mWeekView.setDataRicevuta(Calendar.getTimeInMillis());`

if that works, which it should then your calendarioFooter is the wrong time..

Comment: Now, in the View class result 0. `mToday = Calendar.getInstance();
        mToday.setTimeInMillis(data_ricevuta);
        System.out.println("data_ricevuta " + data_ricevuta);
        mToday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        mToday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);`  Can you see the class WeekView library?

Comment: The calendar `calendarioFooter` is ok, data is passed and received, but when I set, the `System.out.println("data_ricevuta " + data_ricevuta);` is zero.

Comment: to resolve my problem, can I use the sharedpreferences in class View?